# How to make a variable created in a method public?

Tags: java

heyy, i'm a student so dont attack me please i just dont understand whats wrong with this code why is it giving me an error when i make the array public? it says illegal start which doesnt make sense

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment {

 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter array size! ");
        int size= in.nextInt();
        public int[] array= new int[size]; // error
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
'''

any headsup?
```

Comment: Remove `public` in front of your `int[] array`. Variables declared inside methods cannot have *access modifiers* (like `public` or `private`).

Comment: @MCEmperor yes i want to make the array public to use it in other classes

Comment: Insert the line `public static int[] array;` in the class body. Change `public int[] array = new int[size];` to `array = new int[size];` in `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

### Access Modifiers:

If you move the whole line outside of your main function it will work. Access Modifiers such as: "Public, Private, etc." are only allowed outside of functions/methods.

You could also remove the public tag instead of taking the variable out of the function but that would limit your scope.

### Scope:

If you want to learn about scope I'd give this a go:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript/modules/learn-javascript-scope

It's in javascript but don't let that scare you away, the concepts are the same and JS is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Some modifier type are not allowed in method body: `public`, `private`, `protect`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use array outside any class or package then declare array globally with public access modifier.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static int[] array; // declare globally
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter array size! ");
        int size= in.nextInt();
        array = new int[size];
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
            array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```